# how to achieve autocomplete in html?

Tags: html

I have this code `<input type="text" value="destroy" AUTOCOMPLETE="on" />` to enable autocomplete, but it is not working.

Can u tell me any suggestions?

Comment: Try to set the AUTOCOMPLETE="on" on your form element

Answer (score 1):

Auto complete is browser based and should be turned on by default. But usually they only store values that were submitted.

BTW [here's an old SO post about autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag) (just for fun)

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you are trying to achieve. The autocomplete you used serves to offer user a choice from what the user himself typed before.

If you want autocomplete such like search engines have, where user is suggested a number of choices he never typed, then you need to use javascript, and also store somewhere data with autocomplete suggestions.

Here's an example:

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
AUTOCOMPLETE="on"
```

This property is only used by Microsoft Internet Explorer and the default is on. You should only use it to turn it off. If the user turns it off in their browser you can't use it.

Comment: If is it so then is there any option to achive autocomplete functionality in my textbox.?